# How to discover the page code to show a specific character in MSDOS/Batch?

Tags: batch, batch-file, fonts, ms-dos

I made a batch-file snake game and inserted some special characters via HEX to ANSI conversion in Notepad++.
It worked normally. But I noticed that there was an update to the Consolas font and two of the characters became visually the same.
Are they:

[image]
[image]

One of them was slightly larger. I used `chcp 437` (United Stades). But now I have to choose another character. I thought of the U+25CF ● that can be found in the Character's Map (charmap). But I cannot display it on the console.
In the Notepad++ it is shown like that:

[image]

And in the console it shows different things depending on the code page...
**How do I show the black circle with the Consolas font so I don't have to downgrade?**

Comment: After some adaptations and changing characters it's OK with Unicode UTF-8 65001 [https://i.imgur.com/kvfjlFD.png](https://i.imgur.com/kvfjlFD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the UTF-8 Encoding to display Unicode characters.
The following command will set the console to UTF-8:

```
chcp 65001
```

If you wish to set UTF-8 to be the default for all future consoles,
see the post
[Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window).

Comment: I alread tried 65001 and 65000 but is shown a square with a question mark. The file is encoded to UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: `120 x78 x    184 xB8 �    248 xF8 �
121 x79 y    185 xB9 �    249 xF9 �
122 x7A z    186 xBA �    250 xFA �
123 x7B {    187 xBB �    251 xFB �
124 x7C |    188 xBC �    252 xFC �
125 x7D }    189 xBD �    253 xFD �
126 x7E ~    190 xBE �    254 xFE �
127 x7F     191 xBF �    255 xFF �`  I made a small script and most characters appear with question marks, including the black circle x25CF.

Comment: Try adding the BOM, using chcp with UTF-8. You haven't mentioned a file, so how do you display it in the console?

Comment: I said it was a batch-file. It shows through ECHOes. With BOM it doesn't show anything either. It doesn't even run `ECHO`. But anyway giving `TYPE` in the file it shows `%�`

Comment: Hey, I thought to insert this character I would have to insert its hex code. But just giving copy and paste in text editor, it displays normally in console. But I will vote for your help.

Comment: And I'll vote yours.